# How to perform a segue in FBSessionDelegate Method?

Tags: ios, delegates, facebook-ios-sdk

I've got a question about the facebook iPhone SDK, i hope somebody can help me! First of all: i'm using storyboards. In my AppDelegate file I initialize Facebook like this:

```
Start *startController = [[Start alloc] init];
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:startController];
```

As a result of that I can handle the delegate selectors in my StartController. Up to here everything works fine, a facebook user can login and I get information about him. My problem starts here:

```
#pragma mark - FBSessionDelegate Methods
- (void)fbDidLogin {

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self storeAuthData:[[delegate facebook] accessToken] expiresAt:[[delegate facebook] expirationDate]];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"facebookLoginSegue" sender:nil];

}
```

This selector is called when the user successfully logged in. There is a segue called 'facebookLoginSegue' in my storyboard which starts from the viewcontroller. The viewcontroller has got the class 'Start'.

// edit: I've connected the segue to another view controller, of course.

Than I get an error:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Receiver (<Start: 0x94b48d0>) has no segue with identifier 'facebookLoginSegue'
```

I don't understand why the segue cannot be found. I've already tested with an IBAction if that segue exists - but if I do it like that, it works.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? What can I do to perform a segue in that delegate selector? 
Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Any solution?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution ? I'm stuck with the same problem and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

your storyboard file don't have segue @"facebookLoginSegue"
you maybe link @"facebookLoginSegue" to other viewcontroller but not Start ViewController

Comment: I dont't understand your answer. The segue links to another Viewcontroller not to that one which has got the delegates.